# Botbuilder - How to ignore user response without exiting prompt dialog

Tags: node.js, botframework

I have a multipatform bot (node.js through Azure Botframework) that uses a series of prompts to play a game with the user.

In group mode, such as on Kik or Slack, it waits for responses addressed to the bot.

However, I haven't found a way to simply ignore a message that doesn't address the bot. The solution I found ages ago was to simply reply with a new blank prompt:

```
builder.Prompts.text(session, "");
```

And this worked fine. However recently Slack must have changed something, because now this causes an error and the bot restarts.

How do I make the bot ignore certain responses without ending the dialog?

If suggesting a duplicate, please ensure it actually addresses this issue. Many other questions allow for the dialog to end, however this would interrupt the game.

Comment: Have you tried to use bot middileware like use `receive` event to filter the incoming message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup middleware, as mentioned by Gary, that intercepts incoming messages and only processes it if the bot is @mentioned:

```
bot.use({
    botbuilder: function (session, next) {
        var message = session.message;
        var botMri = message.address.bot.id.toLowerCase();
        var botAtMentions = message.entities && message.entities.filter(
            (entity) => (entity.type === "mention") && (entity.mentioned.id.toLowerCase() === botMri));

        if (botAtMentions && botAtMentions.length) {
          next();
        }        
    },
    send: function (event, next) {
        next();
    }
})
```